# How to Clear Web browser control cookies in Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cookies

i want to Clear Web browser control cookies before the new page load .Any way to clear cookies problematically in wp7

Answer (score 3):

For Windows phone 8, there is a simple way

webBroserInstance.ClearCookiesAsync();

In case of WP7, can get cookies using GetCookies method

```
List<Cookie> cookies = webBrowserInstance.GetCookies();
```

Loop through it and try discarding it

```
foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
{
        cookie.Discard = true;
        cookie.Expired = true;
}
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to delete Facebook cookies, but it does not work. Solved the problem by using GetLogoutUrl() from Facebook C# SDK.